# Replace vowels in string with word "oodle" without replacing the vowels in "oodle"

Tags: python

This is my code so far.

```
line = input("Enter a sentence:\n")
for i in range(0,len(line)):
     line = line.replace('a', 'oodle')
     line = line.replace('e', 'oodle')
     line = line.replace('i', 'oodle')
     line = line.replace('o', 'oodle')
     line = line.replace('u', 'oodle')
print(line)
```

However, it replaces the o's and e's in the word "oodle" after replacing them. How can I make it not?

Comment: Why are you looping over the line's length?

Comment: cricket... he would have simillar problems even if he wasnt ...

Comment: What does you intended output look like?

Comment: I would like to, for example, convert "hello" into "hoodlelloodle".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.sub`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[aeiou]', 'ooddle', "test")
'tooddlest'
```

`re.sub` replaces the strings at once, so you won't replace the same string twice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however when I run it, it says "NameError: name 're' is not defined". Do I have to change something?

Comment: Add an `import re` statement to the top of your program

Comment: Now there is no error, but it isn't changing the vowels to oodle. `import re` `line = input()` `re.sub(r'[aeiou]', 'oodle', line)` `print(line)`

Comment: @EthanElzenaar-Adams you're not assigning the result to `line`

Answer (score 1):

This will print 'oodle' if it's a vowel, otherwise it will just keep the consonant:

```
>>>line='hello'
>>>''.join(['oodle' if i in 'aeiou' else i for i in line])
'hoodlelloodle'
```

And if you wanted to keep the vowel and append 'oodle' to it, it would look like:

```
>>>''.join([i+'oodle' if i in 'aeiou' else i for i in line])
'heoodlellooodle'
```

Answer (score 0):

### *If, for some reason, you can't use the re module:*

```
def replace_vowels(string_input, replacement):
    return_string = ""
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    last_vowel = 0
    for i in xrange(0, len(string_input)):
        if string_input[i] in vowels:
            return_string += string_input[last_vowel:i] + replacement
            last_vowel = i + 1
    return return_string

# In [2]: replace_vowels('hello', 'oogle')
# Out[2]: 'hooglelloogle'
```